# Boxplot Pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

DataFrame is as follows:

```
        ID1             ID2 
0   00:00:01.002    00:00:01.002
1   00:00:01.001    00:00:01.006
2   00:00:01.004    00:00:01.011
3   00:00:00.998    00:00:01.012
4       NaT         00:00:01.000
                ...
20      NaT         00:00:00.998
```

What I am trying to do is create a boxplot for each ID. There may or may not be multiple IDs depending on the dataset I provide. For right now I am trying to solve this for 2 datasets. If possible I would like a solution that has all the data on the same boxplot and then another with the data displayed on its own boxplot per ID.

I am very new to pandas (trying to learn it...) and am just getting frustrated at how long this is taking to figure out... Here is my code...

```
deltaTime = pd.DataFrame() #Create blank df
for x in range(0, len(totIDs)):
   ID = IDList[x]
   df = pd.DataFrame(data[ID]).T
   deltaT[ID] = pd.to_datetime(df[TIME_COL]).diff()
deltaT.boxplot()
```

Pretty simple just cant seem to get it do what I want in plotting a boxplot for each ID. I should not that data is given to me by a homegrown file reader that takes several complex files and sorts them into the data dictionary which is indexed by IDs.

I am running pandas version 0.14.0 and python version 2.7.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to plot a box plot of a column of a data frame in two groups in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209795/how-to-plot-a-box-plot-of-a-column-of-a-data-frame-in-two-groups-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this works in `0.14.0` version, because last is `0.19.2` - I recommend upgrade if possible:

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(180)
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 10:11:20', periods=10, freq='T')
cols = ['ID1','ID2']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(dates, size=(10,2)), columns=cols)
print (df)
                  ID1                 ID2
0 2017-01-01 10:12:20 2017-01-01 10:17:20
1 2017-01-01 10:16:20 2017-01-01 10:20:20
2 2017-01-01 10:18:20 2017-01-01 10:17:20
3 2017-01-01 10:12:20 2017-01-01 10:16:20
4 2017-01-01 10:14:20 2017-01-01 10:18:20
5 2017-01-01 10:18:20 2017-01-01 10:19:20
6 2017-01-01 10:17:20 2017-01-01 10:12:20
7 2017-01-01 10:13:20 2017-01-01 10:17:20
8 2017-01-01 10:16:20 2017-01-01 10:11:20
9 2017-01-01 10:13:20 2017-01-01 10:19:20
```

Call [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and then convert `timedeltas` to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df = df.diff().apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds())
print(df)
     ID1    ID2
0    NaN    NaN
1  240.0  180.0
2  120.0 -180.0
3 -360.0  -60.0
4  120.0  120.0
5  240.0   60.0
6  -60.0 -420.0
7 -240.0  300.0
8  180.0 -360.0
9 -180.0  480.0
```

Last use [`DataFrame.plot.box`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.box.html)

```
df.plot.box()
```

[image: graph]

You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots).

Comment: Tried in a rush since I have to leave but I got the following error when doing this line:   pd.to_datetime(df[TIME_COL]).diff().apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds())    I got: AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'dt' .

Comment: You have old version of pandas, so I think it is buggy :(. Please upgrade.

Comment: I cannot upgrade :(... This is for work and the system we are running on cannot change without a minor miracle... Took 1 year last time just to update all the software...